# How to make use of dynamic routing properties using Python for Azure Data Explorer

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-explorer

In Azure-Data-Explorer, while creating a data connection there is an option called my table data contains routing info. how do i make use of it using python? In Azure Samples(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-hubs-dotnet-ingest/blob/master/EventHubSampleData/EventHub2/Program.cs) they are adding routing properties using csharp. how do I achieve the same in python?

```
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
client.run()
try:
    start_time = time.time()
    employess = [
        {
            "empid": 10,
            "name":"Samir",
            "age": 25
        }
    ]
    for i in employess:
        print("Sending Employee: {}".format(json.dumps(i)))

        sender.send(EventData(json.dumps(i)))
except:
    raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python code example in [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25007#issuecomment-495273475):

```
data = {}
tableName = 'TestTable'
tableMapping = 'TestMapping'

event = EventData(json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8'))
event.application_properties = {
    'Table': tableName,
    'Format': "json",
    'IngestionMappingReference': tableMapping,
}
sender.send(event)
```

Just feel free to modify the sample if it does not meet your need.

Comment: you saved my day. It works exactly the way I wanted.